# How can I fix Chrome / Chromium dialog icon sizes on HiDPI?

Tags: chrome

Chrome / Chromium works fine on HiDPI for just about everything, except it isn't working on dialog boxes. The icons are all really tiny, and the theme is a little off. See screenshot:

[image: Chrome HiDPI Problems]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does the same thing happen in other browsers such as Firefox?

Comment: Nope, just Chrome / Chromium.